# Confused about 3rd rule of CFG pumping lemma

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

Let $L = \{\space ww \space | \space w \in \{0,1\}^*$} (need to prove that $L$ is not CFL)

Assuming $L$ is CFL we can use the PL and split $s=uvxyz$ and we choose $s = 0^p1^p0^p1^p$ where $p$ is the pumping length.

Using the 3$^{rd}$ rule, namely $|vxy| \le p$, can I say that $vxy$ can consist only of $0's$ and either pumping up(e.g. $uv^2xy^2z)$ or down ($uxz$) will throw us out of $L$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the PL is stated *for any* partition $s=uvxyz$, so it is not enough to show that for one specific partition pumping $v$ and $y$ will exclude the resulting string from $L$. While it is true that $xyz$ can consist only of 0′s, it could also be the case that $xyz$ is of the form $0^i1^j$ for some $i, j < p$, for instance. You must show that pumping excludes the resulting string from $L$ in this (and all possible other) cases as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a decomposition $s = uvxyz$ such that $|vxy| \leq p$ but $xyz$ doesn't consist only of zeroes:
$$
u = 0^p \\
v = 1^p \\
x = \epsilon \\
y = \epsilon \\
z = 0^p 1^p
$$